how to add multiple configuration in gradle dependencies task
I want to include multiple configuration in the dependencies task in gradle :

gradle -q dependencies --configuration testRuntimeClasspath
I want to add testRuntimeClasspath and also compiletimeClassPath
I tried to do gradle -q dependencies --configuration testRuntimeClasspath,compiletimeClassPath
also
gradle -q dependencies --configuration testRuntimeClasspath --configuration compiletimeClassPath
but always i got an error please help.


Not possible. The task dependencies only accepts a single configuration. You can see that in the source here.
